# Building a Visual Studio 2008 Web applicatio in VWD Express 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have an ASP.NET web application with a web forms projects with dependencies on several business class library projects and a WCF project. This was built with Visual Studio 2008.

I take this source code folder tree to another PC and copy under C:\Inetpub\wwwroot , open IIS and in the properties of the above folder, create application .

I open this as a local Web site with HTTP bindings in Visual Web Developer Express 2008. All the projects now show up as folders.

However, when i build the web site, i get the error as below :-

It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.  c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Foo\FOO\Web.config   39

What is the error and how can i overcome this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that \foo\FOO is not an application. Perhaps you set \foo to be the application?

Comment: That was right - it stopped giving me that error after i made only the actual web folder (foo\foo) as application. However, now it refuses to load Global.asax

Comment: Is global.asax in \foo? It sounds like you need to have a single directory \foo, which should be the application, not two, \foo and \foo\FOO.